# How to wrap div around FULL picture

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, positioning

im working with flexbox atm but the solution doesnt necessarily have to be flexbox related.

these r the code snippets:

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
 height: 50px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

nav span {
  color: seashell;
  padding-right: 30px;

}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration-color: seashell;
}

.mission {
  background-image: url(../images/img-mission-background.jpg);
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 70px;
  width: 1200px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tea Cozy | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="./resources/images/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="our logo">
      <nav>
        <a href="#"><span>Mission</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>Featured Tea</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>Locations</span></a>
      </nav>
        </header>
  <!-- main-content -->
        <div class="mission">
          <div class="mission-banner">
            <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
          </div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Im putting a background-img to the `.mission` div. But it doesnt show the whole picture, it only shows a snipped of it. How do i make the div wrap around the FULL picture? this is what it looks like rn: [image]

i know i could just put the dimensions of the picture to match the height and width of the div but im trying to achieve it some other way. pls explain to me what you did and why and feel free to correct errors (im still learning ^^)

Answer (score 1):

Can't see your images since they aren't hosted online, but I think maybe add background-size: cover to your background image

```
.mission {
  background-image: url(../images/img-mission-background.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  ...
}
```

But if the container just isn't big enough, you could try adding the image to the container and set it's visibility: hidden, this way the container keeps the image dimensions, but it will still have the beautiful background-image showing

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible using a background image, but instead you can use an `<img>` tag which will cause the `.mission` div to expand the full size of the image. You'll need to do some absolute positioning tweaks to get the text to stack on top of the img:

```css
html {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 69px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

header img {
 height: 50px;
 padding-left: 10px;
}

nav span {
  color: seashell;
  padding-right: 30px;

}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration-color: seashell;
}

.mission {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%, -50%);
  width: 1200px;
}
.mission-banner {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.mission img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -425px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tea Cozy | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <img src="./resources/images/img-tea-cozy-logo.png" alt="our logo">
      <nav>
        <a href="#"><span>Mission</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>Featured Tea</span></a>
        <a href="#"><span>Locations</span></a>
      </nav>
        </header>
  <!-- main-content -->
        <div class="mission">
        <div style="position:relative">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/850x350" />
          <div class="mission-banner">
            <h2>Our Mission</h2>
            <h4>Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea</h4>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ty very much ! i just encountered another problem: i cant move the mission-banner to the center (vertical). Any idea?

Comment: @itsolidude updated answer to center mission div horizontally and vertically. Notice that I had to add a new div **inside** of mission to contain the image and text.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the picture as background image. So the element "containing" the picture do not know anything about the dimensions of your picture.

You can add the "background-size" attribute to .mission with the value "cover" so the image will cover the complete div. Or use the value "contain" to show the image complete.

```
.mission {
  background-image: url(../images/img-mission-background.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 70px;
  width: 1200px;
}
```

To make the .mission container bigger, you have to define the width and height of .mission.

Another way could be to add the image as img tag in your .mission and position the content of .mission absolute on top of the image. But maybe this is a little bit wired solution ;)